# Use accepts_nested_attributes_for in a API that is used by RestKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, restkit, nested-attributes

I want to expose an API method that creates an Album with an array of Participants.
This method will be consumed on an iOS device with RestKit.

How should I build the rails API?
How should I configure Restkit?

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, :through => :participants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, :allow_destroy => true

AlbumsController
  def create
    @album = Album.new(params[:album])
    @album.save
```

Comment: could you use httparty for your api call? havent heard of restkit, is is a JSON response